# How to read from local storage in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

```
        var sdcardpath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
        var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdcardpath, "first.html");
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            writer.Write(htmltext);
        }
        else
        {
            var txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
        }
```

In This Way I want to read an html from my local storage But while readalltext am getting exception 
    System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /storage/emulated/0/first.html

Comment: why are you creating a writer and then reading the file?  Why not place the writer inside the if block?

Comment: thank u jason for your info

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);
```

it opens/creates a file at `filepath`. So after this the file always exists (given the path is correct and permissions allow). Then you try to read it but you have it open for writing so this will not be allowed.

If you're trying to see if the file exists and if not, write to it, then move the `StreamWriter` creation inside the check

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true))
    {
        writer.Write(htmltext);
    }
}
else
{
    var txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
}
```

Comment: I got it...but one more problem is once I write text to this whenever I open again am getting empty file how can I rectify that